# selenium more result xpath

Tags: python, selenium

im trying to print all links but i have an error ( ut is not clickable at point (781,748) because another element  obscures it

the code updated:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time


#driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='geckodriver')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

driver.get("https://www.architectes-pour-tous.fr/")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class,'decline-button')]").click();    
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@id='pager']").click();


wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.image-projet img")))
time.sleep(1)
for img in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.image-projet img'):
    print(a.get_attribute('href'))

driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('button.agree-button').click()
pager = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pager"]')
actions.move_to_element(pager).build().perform()
time.sleep(0.5)
pager.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to accept/decline the cookies before accessing any element on the page.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class,'decline-button')]").click();    
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@id='pager']").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

The element you trying to access is initially out of the visible screen so you have to scroll to it before clicking it.
Also possibly you will have to close the accept cookies pop-up prior to clicking this element.
Also I'm quite sure you are getting no links with

```
for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a'):
    print(a.get_attribute('href'))
```

since you trying to do that before the page is loaded.
Also, if you are trying to get the search results links you have to use another locator.
So would suggest to change your code as following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

#driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='geckodriver')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

driver.get("https://www.architectes-pour-tous.fr/")

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.image-projet img")))
time.sleep(1)
for img in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.image-projet img'):
    print(a.get_attribute('href'))

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.agree-button').click()
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
pager = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pager"]')
actions.move_to_element(pager).perform()
time.sleep(0.5)
pager.click()
```

Comment: thanks you, but i have still same error : Message: Element <a id="pager" href="#"> is not clickable at point (781,748) because another element <div class="popup-content info"> obscures it

Comment: Are you sure you used all the code I pasted here?

Comment: hello prophet this is the result :None
`None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "y.py", line 22, in <module>
    driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('button.agree-button').click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'`

Comment: Ah, sure. My typo. Pardon... Fixed that. It should be `find_element_by_css_selector` there, not `find_elements_by_css_selector`

Comment: now i have    actions.move_to_element(pager).build().perform()
AttributeError: 'ActionChains' object has no attribute 'build' and i changed print(a.get_attribute('href') to print(img.get_attribute('href')

Comment: You can try use it without `build()`, `perform()` may be enought

Comment: hello prophet ,  now diferent error : selenium.common.exceptions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: (796, 2359) is out of bounds of viewport width (1283) and height (775)
do u have ty the code ?

Comment: I have added `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")` this should help