# How to make Python wait for popup in website?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use selenium webdriver with Python to log in to a website. But on this website, once I press the login button a popup in the website shows up and I have to click a button on the popup. The website was not made very well, and the time it takes for the popup to show up in the website varies each time, sometimes it takes a few seconds and sometimes it could take 15-20. I was wondering if there was a way I could make Python wait until it detects the popup or the button I need to press on screen, then continue with the function and click the button.

Comment: just try to use time.sleep(30) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can and should use explicit waits on this case.
For example if the button closing the pop up can be located with `button.close-pop-up` selector you can use this command:

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.close-pop-up"))).click()
```

To use it you will need to import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

And initialize the `wait` object by

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
```

For an example code see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68144564/selenium-more-result-xpath/68149585#68149585) discussion or any other selenium code utilizing "expected conditions"